# Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'UIImage'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimage, xcode7.2

In my project contain this following line of code. But I always get the error. I am using Xcode 7.2 and iOS 9.

```
let image: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage:imageRef, scale:originalImage.scale, orientation:originalImage.imageOrientation)!
```

Comment: remove the exclamation mark...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `!`

The result of that method isn't optional - you don't need to unwrap it.

NB You don't need the `: UIImage` from the variable - Swift will infer it's type for you.

---

EDIT: What if `imageRef` is optional (from @chewie's comment)?

You have a few options.

1 Use `if let`:

```
if let imageRef = imageRef {
   let image = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef, scale: originalImage.scale, orientation: originalImage.imageOrientation)

    // Do something with image here
}
```

2 Use `guard`

```
guard let imageRef = imageRef else {
    print("Oops, no imageRef - aborting")
    return
}

// Do something with image here
let image = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef, scale: originalImage.scale, orientation: originalImage.imageOrientation)
```

3 Use map

```
let image = imageRef.map {
    UIImage(CGImage: $0, scale: originalImage.scale, orientation: originalImage.imageOrientation)
}

// Do something with image here, remembering that it's 
// optional this time :)
```

The choice of which to use is yours, but here's my rule of thumb.

If what you need to do *requires* an image, use `guard` and abort early if you don't have one. This generally makes your code easier to read and understand.

If what you need to do can be done without an image, use `if let` or `map`. `if let` is useful if you just want to maybe do something and then carry on. `map` is useful if you need to pass your `UIImage?` around and use it later.

Comment: If I do, Xcode complains the optional type "CGImage?" is not unwrapped.

Comment: Ah - you've got a slightly different issue - I think your `imageRef` is optional. I've edited my answer, hope it helps.